# What do we learn from the huge cluster of grapes?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment

The spies brought back a huge cluster of grapes, on a pole carried by lifting it at both ends.  Presumably that sample was typical of the produce.

Was the land equally fertile 40 years later when we entered the land?  If not, why is there no mention of that.  If so, when did the land become less fertile?

Comment: I think the 2nd paragraph should be a separate question. There doesn't appear to be a direct relationship to the grapes and the land's fertility. The fertility issue is more related to wheat, and that is addressed via a separate request from Moses when he said "See if the land is 'fat or skinny'. Can you edit your question so that it is more focused? I don't want to post an irrelevant answer.

Comment: @DanF  Only a fertile land would produce grape clusters so large that they would need to be carried on a pole.  In any case, I do not understand the distinction that you see so clearly.  Pls restate or explain.